# Ruby Search by using input

Tags: ruby

modify this code to create search by first name using user input output must show age and title

```
# A simple Employee class
class Employee
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :title, :age

  def initialize(fname, lname, title, age)
    @first_name = fname
    @last_name = lname
    @title = title
    @age = age
  end
  # A string representation of the Employee object
  def to_s
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}, #{title}, #{age}"
  end
end
# The collection class for Employee objects
class Employees
  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    @employees = []
  end
  # Add Employee objects to the collection
  def <<(employee)
    @employees << employee
  end
  # Method mandated by the Enumerable module
  def each
    @employees.each { |e| yield(e) }
  end
end
employees = Employees.new

employees << Employee.new('Anita', 'Baker', 'President', 48)
employees << Employee.new('Frank', 'Gifford', 'Director', 58)
employees << Employee.new('Barbara', 'Eden', 'Secretary', 34)
employees << Employee.new('George', 'Clooney', 'Project Manager', 37)
employees << Employee.new('Emily', 'Davies', 'Programmer', 28)
employees << Employee.new('David', 'Faber', 'Programmer', 55)
employees << Employee.new('Cindy', 'Adams', 'Programmer', 33)
employees << Employee.new('Helen', 'Hamilton', 'Business Analyst', 42)
```

Comment: Anything else you would like us to do?

Comment: yeah i would like to know how to make search only show specif parts.Like when searching for first name output only would show age basically how to add conditions thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already done all the necessary work by implementing `Enumerable` interface.  Just accept user input and call the `Enumerable#find` method:

```
fname = gets.chomp
e = employees.find {|i| i.first_name == fname}
```